# Strange behavior of numpy.round

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, rounding

Python's `round()` seems to always round up when faced with x.5 numbers:

```
print round(1.5),round(2.5),round(3.5),round(4.5)
>>> 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
```

But `numpy.round()` seems to be inconsistent:

```
import numpy as np
print np.round(1.5),np.round(2.5),np.round(3.5),np.round(4.5)
>>> 2.0 2.0 4.0 4.0
```

This can introduce errors in certain cases. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: It's rounding to the nearest even integer for faster binary calculation.

Comment: It's worth noting that this behaviour changed between Python 2 and Python 3; Python 3 behaves the same as NumPy here.

Comment: @Mikael: I don't think speed has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

numpy rounds to the nearest even value:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc.

Comment: This is specifically called [Round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) and is useful because it does not introduce bias. This is especially important in finance, which it's sometimes called "bankers' rounding"

Comment: Oddly enough, I've taught Python and NumPy to a lot of bankers from many different companies, and very few of them recognised this rounding mode ...