# Subtract time value to column of times in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, time, subtraction

I have a column of times like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'times':['10:59:20.1647', '11:05:46.2258', '11:10:59.4658']})
```

my goal is to subtract to all this times the the first time. In order to do so, I converted the column to `datetime.time` type and subtracted the first value to all the column:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['times']).dt.time - pd.to_datetime(df['times']).dt.time.iloc[0]
```

However, by doing so I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and'datetime.time'
```

Could you suggest a smart and elegant way in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timedeltas`:

```
a = pd.to_timedelta(df['times'])
b =  a - a.iat[0]
print (b)
0          00:00:00
1   00:06:26.061100
2   00:11:39.301100
Name: times, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And if need times:

```
c = pd.to_datetime(b).dt.time
print (c)
0           00:00:00
1    00:06:26.061100
2    00:11:39.301100
Name: times, dtype: object

print (c.apply(type))
0    <class 'datetime.time'>
1    <class 'datetime.time'>
2    <class 'datetime.time'>
Name: times, dtype: object
```

---

Another solution with output `timedelta`:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df['times'])
b =  a - a.iat[0]
print (b)
0          00:00:00
1   00:06:26.061100
2   00:11:39.301100
Name: times, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Just one last thing: lets say I want to round the seconds based on the decimals what should I do? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So what is desired output from `00:06:26.061100` ?

Comment: 00:06:26.061100 would be 00:06:26 /
00:06:28.510000 would be 00:06:28

Comment: You can use `print (b.dt.round('S'))` but it round a bit defferent as you think - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021321/2901002) for explanation.