# Rounding pandas timestamps to nearest 10min

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe indexed with three pandas timestamps:

```
import pandas as pd

ts1=pd.Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:05:00')
ts2=pd.Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:15:00')
ts3=pd.Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:25:00')

df=pd.DataFrame(index=[ts1, ts2, ts3])
```

Now I want to round the timestamp indexes to their nearest 10min:

```
df.index.round('10min')
```

But I get some unexpected output:

> ```
> DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-01 00:00:00', '2017-06-01 00:20:00',
>                '2017-06-01 00:20:00'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
> ```

Note that the `2017-06-01 00:20:00` timestamp appears twice. Is this correct behaviour? My desired output is:

> ```
> DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-01 00:00:00', '2017-06-01 00:10:00',
>                '2017-06-01 00:20:00'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
> ```

Can I achieve this using the pandas round function? Any other suggestions for rounding pandas timestamps?

I'm using pandas 0.23.1

Comment: Yes, rounding is done to the nearest even number. If you want consistency, I recommend `df.index.floor('10min')`.

Comment: I'm still confused, how come 00:15:00 is rounded UP and 00:25:00 is rounded DOWN? Does not look consistent to me...

Comment: @Nickj Numpy uses a rounding algorithm called "Banker's Rounding", which is a method of rounding to the nearest even integer to reduce bias. The reason for datetimes exhibiting the same behaviour is due to implementation details in pandas.

Comment: @coldspeed Where did you find an explanation to this?

Comment: @Abhishek [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021268/strange-behavior-of-numpy-round) explores the detail. As for why pandas exhibits the same behaviour.. that's because numpy is pandas' backbone.

Comment: Is there any way to switch from banker's rounding to round-half-up or round-half-down rounding?

Comment: Like I said `df.index.floor('10min')` or `df.index.ceil('10min')` if you prefer that.

Comment: hmm, but the problem is, I would still like a timestamp like 2017-06-01 00:29:00 to be rounded UP... Suggestions?

Comment: @Nickj yeah, I don't think you can get that with numpy or pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of cleanup of your code as below, it does not mix levels of abstration and is more easily tested, hope also a bit more readable:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def is_exactly(x, minutes):
    return np.abs(x) == pd.to_timedelta(minutes * 60,unit='S')

def round_timestamp(ts):    
    floor=ts.floor('10 min')
    rounded=ts.round('10 min')    
    if is_exactly(rounded-ts, 5):
        return floor 
    else: 
        return rounded  

dt = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:15:00')
assert round_timestamp(dt) == pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:10:00')
```

Myself, I would be happy to learn how a frequency `10min` tag can be converted to minutes?

Comment: OK, looks good and much more understandable than mine. Though it looks like mine is faster for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a function that rounds timestamps the way I need them to be rounded:

```
def rounding_timestamps(df):
    import numpy as np

    rounded_values_floor=df.index.floor('10min')
    rounded_values=df.index.round('10min')

    diff=np.abs(rounded_values-df.index) 

    output=rounded_values.values

    I_floor=diff==pd.to_timedelta(300,unit='S') # 5min  
    output[I_floor] = rounded_values_floor[I_floor].values

    return pd.to_datetime(output)
```

Basically I use normal rounding, but switch to floor rounding whenever a timestamp is exactly halfway.

Works for me, but I would appreciate a more elegant solution.

Comment: why don't you want your function to work on one level of abstraction? you seem to date whole dataframe and return just dates?