# Different round behaviour for Python round on float and numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, rounding

I stumpled into a test failure caused by floating point precision and am trying to understand it.

In short: **Python3** `round` returns a different value depending on whether the type is a float or a numpy.float64 although I thought `float==double==float64` and both Python**3** and NumPy should round nearest to even.

Here the example:

```
npVal = np.float64(435)/100
pyVal = 435/100
print(round(npVal,1))             // 4.4
print(round(pyVal,1))             // 4.3
print(round(np.float64(pyVal),1)) // 4.4
print(round(float(npVal),1))      // 4.3
```

I understand that 4.35 and 4.4 might not be exactly representable in double but why is numpy round differently than Python although they both use the same datatypes and specify the function similar? I used the explicit division to avoid input rounding errors.

I don't know for sure, whether the double value for 4.35 is a bit more or less, so I can't say **which** of those implementations is (might be?) wrong.

There is a similar question: [Strange behavior of numpy.round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021268/strange-behavior-of-numpy-round)

There it was noted, that NumPy "rounds to the nearest even value" and "behaviour changed between Python 2 and Python 3; Python 3 behaves the same as NumPy here".

So both should do the same and round to nearest even value. So **if** 4.35 would be an exact float, 4.4 would the correct answer and needed to be returned by both.

Comment: They are both right, `4.35` is the same distance on the number line from `4.4` as it is from `4.3`. You could try allowing a higher number of decimals to kick the can a little farther down the road.

Comment: Both implementations of `round` should round to even as explained in a comment to the linked question: "It's worth noting that this behaviour changed between Python 2 and Python 3; Python 3 behaves the same as NumPy here." I'm asking why this is not the case?

Comment: @coldspeed This isn't a duplicate: the other question was about Python 2, this question uses a `print` function, so is using Python 3, where they should have the same behaviour.

Comment: Python's `round` is correctly-rounded (but slow). NumPy's is not (but is faster). Different tradeoffs. (Agreed that this isn't a duplicate.)

Comment: @coldspeed: That question is not a duplicate. It says `numpy.round` rounds to even for values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values. But the `npVal` in this question cannot be exactly halfway between 4.3 and 4.4 because 4.35 is not representable in 64-bit binary floating-point. The closest representable value is 4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375, which ought to round down.

Comment: Thanks. As the suggested question might still be relevant I added it to my question and summarized what I wrote here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating 435/100 in IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point yields 4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375.

When this is rounded to the nearest decimal numeral with one digit after the decimal point, the result ought to be “4.3”. The Python rounding for this case appears to be correct.

For `numpy.round`, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html#numpy.ndarray.round) refers to `numpy.around`. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) for that says “Results may also be surprising due to … errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten.” Thus, it may be that `numpy.round` does not calculate the correct conversion of 4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 to decimal but rather performs a 64-bit binary floating-point multiplication of that by 10, which yields exactly 43.5 due to floating-point rounding, and then `numpy.round` rounds that to 44 and formats it as “4.4”.

In summary, `numpy.round` is not a correct rounding routine.

Comment: It seems you are correct for numpy: As far as I understand the code it does a multiply by 10^x and then a round to int and divide: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9d0225b800df3c2b0bffee9960df87b15527509c/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L715 This would be the only possible implementation of round to decimals I can think of. Any idea what Python3 does?

Comment: @Flamefire: Python is generally implemented by relying on the underlying platform. One can “easily” convert binary floating-point to exact decimal using techniques taught in elementary school, but straightforward implementations require more time and memory than is desired. Expert techniques to convert efficiently are known and published and are increasingly built into standard library functions such as C’s `printf` and `scanf`. (Doing it efficiently is interesting and somewhat hard.) But I could not tell you from my own knowledge what any particular Python implementations do.

Comment: @Flamefire: On most platforms (those where the underlying floating-point format can be identified as IEEE 754), CPython versions 2.7 and 3.1 and later use dedicated correctly-rounded binary-to-decimal and decimal-to-binary conversions, based on well-known code by David Gay. The key source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/dtoa.c)